# Test image upload in using spring boot in postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I am currently, scratching my head on this and wonder what is the method to test this post mapping in postman.  I haven't been able to find a way to accomplish using the body->form-data method:

Model class:

```
@Document(collection = "${collections}")
public class DogPics {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private Binary image;

    public DogPics(String title, Binary image) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Binary getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Binary image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public DogPics() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DogPics(String title) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Post method:

```
@Autowired
DogPicsService photoService;

@PostMapping("/photos/add")
public String addPhoto(@RequestParam("title") String title, 
  @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image, Model model) 
  throws IOException {
    String id = photoService.addPhoto(title, image);
    return "redirect:/photos/" + id;
}
```

I will also add that, I was following the guide for uploading images from [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mongodb-upload-file) java tutorial website.

#**Update for the work around:**

I just changed the requestparam to requestpart as shown below and it works with postman now:

```
@PostMapping("/photos/add")
    public String addPhoto(@RequestPart("title") String title, 
      @RequestPart("image") MultipartFile image, Model model) 
      throws IOException {
        String id = photoService.addPhoto(title, image);
        return "redirect:/photos/" + id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file through POSTMAN, by navigating to body -> form-data
Enter the key as "image" (from your question) and select File from dropdown next to key, Upload option will appear in Value column.

This is how you can test your endpoint.

[image]

Comment: is there any changes to headers required?

Comment: I am still getting a 404 error when trying the above method.

Comment: Content-type should be set as multipart/form-data in Headers.

Comment: Will this only pull from the requestbody.